# How to use jQuery SVG to change the transformation with the variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

like this:

```
svg.configure({viewBox: '0 0 100 100'}, true);
svg.configure({transform:'translate(100,200)'},true);
```

it works ok!
But how do I put the variable to the setting?
like this:

```
var X=100;
var Y=200;
var width=500;
var height=400;
var newX=100;
var newY=200;
svg.configure({viewBox: 'X Y wdth height'}, true);
svg.configure({transform:'translate(newX,newY)'},true);
```

it can't work?
How do I put the variables in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="jquery.svg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawInitial});
        });

        function drawInitial(svg) {
            var X=0;
            var Y=0;
            var width=500;
            var height=600;
            var newX=100;
            var newY=100;
            svg.configure({viewBox: X + " " + Y + " " + width + " " + height}, true);


            var circle = svg.circle(75, 75, 50, {fill: 'none', stroke: 'red', 'stroke-width': 3});
            var g = svg.group({stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 2});
            var line = svg.line(g, 15, 75, 135, 75);
            var line2 = svg.line(g, 75, 15, 75, 135);

            svg.configure(line, {transform:'translate(' + newX + ',' + newY + ')'},true);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="svgbasics"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will create a new string via concatenation with the values of newX and newY such that the javascript interpreter will see

```
'translate(100,200)'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it still cannot work by the code:
  
svg.configure({transform:'translate(' + newX + ',' + newY + ')'},true);  

it cannot catch the variables(newX and newY),just use the default (0,0)..I check the help in the website but cannot find the solution!
http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#configure

Comment: I find the svg.configure({viewBox: '0 0 100 100'}, true);
it works like =>     viewBox='0 0 100 100' (it's right!)
But the
svg.configure({transform:'translate(0, 10)'},true);
it cannot work as=> transform="'translate(0, 10)'" (this " ' is wrong)
it must be the transform="translate(0, 10)" but when I write the code svg.configure({transform:translate(0,10)}); it cannot work still! Is it  a bug by the jquery SVG?

Comment: I have added a more complete example.  If you comment out the transform you will see the first line appear.  One thing I couldn't determine was why the transform forces the line off the screen, but that is a separate question.

Comment: It works on the line. I use the work on the <svg transform:'translate(10,10) > . It failed. I mistake the "transform" applicable on the <svg> tag. It just can use on other element but not the <svg>. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I Suggest `.change` function on the node instead of `.configure`

```
svg.change(Node, { transform: 'translate(' + newX + ',' + newY + ')' });
//Node can be any of the svg nodes from Eric's solution
```

the last parameter if set to true removes all other attributes hence i guess `.change` would work better.